# Cannot read Excel file using U-SQL

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, u-sql

I am trying to read an Excel file and have to write in a csv file in Azure Datalake.
When I am trying to do it then it is showing error.

**U-SQL Script:**

```
DECLARE @ExcelFile = @"/Output/demog_data_Merged_08022017.xlsx";

@result01 = EXTRACT Id string,
UNIQUE_ID long,
SOL_ID int,
EMAIL_ID string,
mobilenumber string,
CUST_OPN_DATE DateTime,
gender char,
age int,
CUR_CITY string,
CUR_COUNTRY string,
CUR_PIN string,
NRE_CNTRY string,
MARITAL_STATUS char,
FREZ_CODE char,
UNFREEZ_DATE DateTime,
LAST_FREZ_DATE DateTime,
DORMANCY_STATUS char,
AVAILABLE_AMOUNT double,
ACCOUNT_OPEN_DATE DateTime,
nullcol string,
Salaried_account_flag char,
ACCOUNT_TYPE string
FROM @ExcelFile
USING new oh22is.Analytics.Formats.ExcelExtractor("result01");


@result02 = SELECT * FROM @result01;

OUTPUT @result02 TO "/output/demog_for_report.csv"
USING Outputters.Csv();
```

**Error:**

```
{
    "errorCode": "2703",
    "message": "Error Id: E_CSC_USER_INVALIDCSHARP, Error Message: C# error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'oh22is' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?). ",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "U-SQL1"
}
```

Comment: Aren't you missing a REFERENCE ASSEMBLY  instruction or did you not post the whole script? See https://github.com/Azure/AzureDataLake/blob/master/Samples/ExcelExtractor/USQLExcelExtractor/ReadExcel.usql for an example

Comment: Should I write `USING new ExcelExtractor("result01");` instead of `USING new oh22is.Analytics.Formats.ExcelExtractor("result01");`

Comment: No, you have to register and reference the assembly, as stated in the example

Answer (score 0):

Excel files cannot be read without an assembly reference. You need the files `DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll` and `oh22is.Analytics.Formats.dll` in your data lake directory, alongside with your excel file (not necessarily at the same folder).

Assembly references hold the file reading logic and act as a gateway between the u-sql internal representation of data and the file format that, yielding data as it can be processed.

Sadly these files are not distributed individually as far as I know and Microsoft seems to demands you to compile it manually [from  source](https://github.com/Azure/AzureDataLake/tree/master/Samples/ExcelExtractor/oh22is.Analytics.Formats) with [this repository](https://github.com/Azure/AzureDataLake/) with Visual Studio. The good thing about using VS is that you can reference the assemblies directly to fasten your development (but I find it pointless, since I only use it for excel extracting and only need to generate the files once). The compilation process should also give you the dynamic linked library from the `documentformat.openxml` [package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/), so that you don't have to download it or extract it from the `.nupkg` file, which, if you do, prefer to use the version at `/lib/net40/DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll`, which is what worked for my xlsx file (2007-2019 format).

After putting the assembly files (two `.dll` files) in your data lake, make note of their path and use them like the following u-sql script:

```
// Register the dependency to the analytics assembly (xml file reader)
DROP ASSEMBLY IF EXISTS openxml;
CREATE ASSEMBLY openxml FROM @"/MyProject/Assemblies/DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll";
REFERENCE ASSEMBLY openxml;

// Register the analytics assembly that read our excel file
DROP ASSEMBLY IF EXISTS analytics;
CREATE ASSEMBLY analytics FROM @"/MyProject/Assemblies/oh22is.Analytics.Formats.dll";
REFERENCE ASSEMBLY analytics;

// Define a local variable for the excel file
DECLARE @ExcelFile = @"/MyProject/MyFolder/test-file.xlsx";

@sheet = EXTRACT
    A string,
    B string,
    C string
FROM @ExcelFile
    USING new oh22is.Analytics.Formats.ExcelExtractor("Sheet1");

//And you can save, transform, select it like you would use any other data:

OUTPUT (SELECT * FROM @sheet) TO "/MyProject/output.csv" USING Outputters.Csv();
```